# CSS font display not as supposed

Tags: html, css

I have a current state of a font section on my website on the right side called: "Words is the place where you can create your own story out of 3 words!"

Website for styles: http://words.goldwingstudios.de

But I want it to look like this:

[image: Expected font styles]

Here is the source code for this section:

```
<div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_container">
    <div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes">
        "
    </div>
    <div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan">
        Words is the place where you can create your own story out of <b class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes_textbig">3</b> words!
    </div>
    <div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes">
        "
    </div>
    <div class="fix_float"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.__log_reg_preview_slogan_container
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    font-family: words_chat_text;
}

.__log_reg_preview_slogan
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 101px;
}

.__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes:not(:first-child)
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your CSS look like? And what is the font looking like currently?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to format your double quotes which are wrapped around your text???

Comment: yes? where is the problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I want to format the two quotes from my existing code like in the image example from my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New CSS Class**

```
.bottom_quote {
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Add the class to the bottom quote:

```
<div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_container">
    <div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes bottom_quote">
        "
    </div>
    <div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan">
        Words is the place where you can create your own story out of <b class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes_textbig">3</b> words!
    </div>
    <div class="__log_reg_preview_slogan_quotes">
        "
    </div>
    <div class="fix_float"></div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks sir!